# Moving FSMO Roles from SBS to Server 2016

Tags: migration, windows-server-2016

I am migrating from a `Windows Small Business Server 2008` to a `Windows Server 2016` and am looking at the final steps moving the fsmo roles over to the new server. I am following [this guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/05/24/step-by-step-migrating-active-directory-fsmo-roles-from-windows-server-2012-r2-to-2016/) (starting from 'Migrate FSMO to Server 2016). First step is to query who actually holds the roles with `netdom`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netdom query fsmo
Schema master               [sourceserver].[domain].local
Domain naming master        [sourceserver].[domain].local
PDC                         [sourceserver].[domain].local
RID pool manager            [sourceserver].[domain].local
Infrastructure master       [sourceserver].[domain].local
The command completed successfully.
```

this looks as expected so I run the next commen (PowerShell on the Target Server)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity [targetserver] -OperationMasterRole SchemaMaster
, DomainNamingMaster, PDCEmulator, RIDMaster, InfrastructureMaster
```

just it's throwing an error at me which I don't know what to make of.

```
Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity COMSRV2018 -Opera ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (COMSRV2018:ADDirectoryServer) [Move-ADDirector...ationMasterRole],
    ADServerDownException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1355,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADDirectory
   ServerOperationMasterRole
```

Running the`netdom`query again it still indicates the fsmo roles being with the source server.

One obvoius effect is that I have a lot of [red indicators in the target servers Daschboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1pN.png) which all say `Online - restart pending`

[image: red indicators in the target servers Daschboard]

I am hesitant to just restart the server due to the error I got. Can someone advise what to do at this point?
My guide would tell me to:
**`Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -DemoteOperationMasterRole -RemoveApplicationPartition`** on the source server (but only **after** the Moving of the roles was successfull (which it wasn't in my scenario)

any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: found a hint [here](https://www.itpromentor.com/sbs-ad-mig/) mentioning an outdated powershell on the sourceserver as a potential reason. Also it says 'the GUI way works well'. I guess then the next step would be to release the roles on the source server in the source servers GUI.

Comment: on the source server hanging at 'initializing the removal process' on the SBS source server (>Server Manager >Remove Roles >Active Directory Certifiate Service) now

Answer (score 1):

The Active Directory PowerShell module requires domain controllers to run Active Directory Web Services, which were introduced in Windows Server 2008 R2; a Windows Server 2008 DC doesn't have them, thus the error.

You should move the roles using `NTDSUTIL`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you must use powershell?

I've been through this several times and I always use NTDSUTIL to do the transfer of roles.

Heres the MS website: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/255504/using-ntdsutil-exe-to-transfer-or-seize-fsmo-roles-to-a-domain-control

About the middle of the page there are the simple steps for this.

I think ntdsutil has been around longer than powershell, and I trust it for that reason.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the tip. And no, the only reason for Powershell was that I stumbled over that how-to and didn't know any better (Zero to none experience with Windows server on our end). In the end we managed to finish this through the GUI somehow. Can't really say how though unfortunately (was kind of a hell ride) but it seems to have worked in the end. thanks anyway, will come back to your suggestion whether I'll have to do it ever again.